# Overriding default malloc library in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm looking for a way to override the default malloc library in Ubuntu.
I have created my own malloc library which includes malloc / free / realloc / calloc, and would like to try to start programs with it.

So far I tried LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out but it's still using the system library (I know because I placed a write in the malloc function to verify it's mine).

What am I missing ?

Comment: You could also call them something *other* than the standard names, like e.g. `my_malloc` and call `my_malloc` explicitly.

Comment: I did this during the implementation, however I want to know if my malloc can handle stuff like vim, zsh and so on, and for that I need to use the standard name.